# is amazon sns with IPHONE will work with offline..if not is there any way to achieve?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, amazon-sns

When I publish notification to specific endpoint from amazon console when device in offline mode.. after making device online notification not getting delivered.. is there any setting to make it possible..

Or as because sandbox not working?

Please help some one.

Comment: Did you try setting a Time to live (TTL) ?

Comment: @ryancrunchi doesn't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figure it out.. we have an option to integration application with amazon SQS using topic subscription using SQS service.. once topic created we just need bind topic to application event.